# Pulling information from a mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm attempting to search a mysql database based on criteria entered by the user. The script here is attempting to pull an entry based on the product key. But, when I search for a key that I know exists in the table, nothing is returned. I am extremely new to php so this code could be completely wrong. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">

<title>
Inventory Home Page
</title>

<body>
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myaccount", "mypass", "Inventory");
    mysql_select_db("db_test", $link);
if(!$link){
    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error($link));
}

    $productKey = %product_key_search%;
    $query = mysql_query("select * from PC where pk=$productKey") or die(mysql_error($link));

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo 'Product Key: ' .$row['pk'];
        echo 'Make: ' .$row['make'];
        echo 'Model: ' .$row['model'];
        echo 'Type: ' .$row['type'];
        echo 'Content: ' .$row['content'];
        echo 'Status: ' .$row['status'];
        echo 'Workstation: ' .$row['asset'];
        echo 'Steam Account Number: ' .$row['steam_acct_num'];

    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help..

Comment: You forgot to close your `<head>` tag, and you should use consistent of mysql or mysqli class.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is full of too many errors to be a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">

<title>
Inventory Home Page
</title>

<body>
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "myaccount", "mypass", "Inventory");
    mysql_select_db("db_test", $link);
if(!$link){
    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error($link));
}

   $statement = "select * from PC where pk LIKE %".$productKey."%";
    $query = mysql_query( $statement) or die(mysql_error($link));

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo 'Product Key: ' .$row['pk'];
        echo 'Make: ' .$row['make'];
        echo 'Model: ' .$row['model'];
        echo 'Type: ' .$row['type'];
        echo 'Content: ' .$row['content'];
        echo 'Status: ' .$row['status'];
        echo 'Workstation: ' .$row['asset'];
        echo 'Steam Account Number: ' .$row['steam_acct_num'];

    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to close your `<head>` tag and you're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_`

Comment: Your solution should have used mysqli, not the obsolete mysql functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes around your string value. Also, if you are using the `%` wildcard you need to use `LIKE`, not `=`:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from PC where pk=$productKey") or die(mysql_error($link));
```

should be:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from PC where pk LIKE '$productKey'") or die(mysql_error($link));
```

Additionally, you would have the first error if you had actually checked for errors in your code. You should be using [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error) to see if an error occurred before trying to retrieve your result set.

You should also change `mysqli_fetch_array()` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` as you do not need both a numerical and key based indexed array of results.

And, as pointed out by @Pitchinnate you are mixing mysql and mysqli functions. This looks like copy and paste code. You should understand code *before* you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mysqli_connect` then the rest are all `mysql_` functions. These can not be mixed.

Comment: And that too. Too many errors in this question. Going to vote to close.